# What is the maximum number of warriors one can put on a chess board so that no two warriors attack each other?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, proof-writing, contest-math, chessboard

> In chess, a normal knight goes two steps forward and one step to the side, in some orientation. Thanic thought that he should spice the game up a bit, so he introduced a new kind of piece called *a warrior*. A *warrior* can either go three steps forward and one step to the side, or two steps forward and two steps to the side in some orientation.
> Given a $2020\times2020$ chess board. Find, with proof, the maximum number of warriors one can put on its cells such that no two warriors attack each other.

The question is a modified version of a problem from Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2019. For more clarity, here is a picture that shows example moves of a *warrior*:
[image: Moves of a warrior]

This is my first time solving this kind of problem. I've made the following progress in solving the question:

We place the warriors in each cell of $n$-th column where $n\equiv1\ (\bmod 4)$. The following picture shows this strategy in an $8\times8$ board:
[image]
It can be seen that no two *warriors* can
attack each other. Hence, the answer to our original problem should be $2020\times505$.

Though this result matches with the original answer, I have still some confusions. Firstly, the optimal strategy is that in the $2020\times2020$ board, we place a warrior in each cell of $n$-th column. But what if we don't place them with that strategy or we just randomly place the *warriors* so that they cannot attack each other? How will I know other strategies would not give a result greater than $2020\times 505$? More specifically, how do I write a formal proof for this kind of problems?

Comment: Regarding your confusion, just because you have the numerical value, doesn't mean that your proof is correct. Like you realized, for a complete solution, you also need to show that "no other strategies will give a larger number". Similar to when we want to show something is a maximum, we need to show A) It can be achieved (which you have done) and B) No larger value can be achieved.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, my question is regarding B.

Comment: Note that the actual BDMO question doesn't ask to find the exact maximum, but asks to show that the maximum is $\leq \frac{2}{5} \times 2020 \times 2020 $ [Source - BdMO 2019 Higher Secondary Qn 10](https://matholympiad.org.bd/resources/all-questions/file/20-bdmo-2019-national).  This greatly changes how one can approach the question.

Comment: In your post, you stated "This question is from Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2020.", but not that you modified it (so strictly speaking, it isn't from there). $\quad$ While I haven't seen the solution, I don't think this is "a bit modified". I suspect that to find the actual maximum, it will involve a lot more machinery. Please go to the actual source when you can. Even your link states the actual problem in the second post.

Comment: @CalvinLin The question is from BDMO 2019 (That was a mistake, I edited the source). And yes, I am aware of the actual problem. But as I said, I am rather interested in finding the exact maximum.

Comment: I'm pointing out that we have no reason to believe that $2020 \times 505$ is indeed the true maximum. Just because you've found a maximal configuration (in the sense that you cannot add another warrior), doesn't mean that there isn't another configuration where we can place even more warriors. Such a question can be extremely tough to answer exactly, because you're only providing very local restriction (with no easy "defining feature"), and asking for global information. I recommend that you look at the solution to understand why they only went with 2/5, and then see if you can optimize.

Comment: @CalvinLin From [this AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1793768p11879854) it seemed to me that the answer would be $2020\times 505$ as many users agreed to have that answer. And regarding the actual problem, I don't know if there is an official solution but I thought of a solution which seems quite easy to me (I may be wrong). You said "you're only providing very local restriction (with no easy defining feature)"- what you meant by local restriction is not clear to me.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Any improvement suggestions are welcome, I will improve my question accordingly.

Comment: 1) Math isn't correct by majority vote (at least at the level of the answer to this problem). Even in the thread, they are being questioned on why that is the maximum, and cannot provide a suitable proof.  2) Can you add your solution to 2/5? 3) The local restriction is "this square disallows 12 other squares", which is hard to relate to "what is the maximum set?".

Comment: Put another way, take the graph theoretic interpretation where the square are vertices and edges connect squares that attack each other. We have $ 2020 \times 2020$ vertices with degree (at most) 12 (main local restriction, though there are others like no 3-cycle.). What is the size of the largest independent set (global information)? We might be able to get bounds on the size, but finding the actual size will greatly depend on the graph. This is why I said your version will require a lot more machinery.

Comment: Notice that the problem decomposes into two separate problems: one for the black squares and one for the red squares.

Answer (score 6):

$505\times 2020=1,\!020,\!100$ is certainly not optimal. By tiling a $2019\times 2020$ board with a rectangular pattern of the following $3\times 5$ rectangle, you can fit $$4\times  \frac{2019}3\times \frac{2020}{5}=1,\!087,\!568\newcommand{\W}{\mathsf{W}}$$ warriors onto a $2019\times 2020$ board alone.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&&\;\W\;&&\phantom{\Big(\;\;}
\\\hline
&\;\W\,&&\;\W\;&\phantom{\Big(\;\;\;\,}
\\\hline
\phantom{\Big(\;\;\;}&&\W&&
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
You strategy achieves a density of $1/4$ warriors/square, while mine has a density of $4/15$, so the latter should always be better for large enough boards. I do not know if this can be improved at all.

---

Let $D$ be the optimal packing density for warriors. In addition to the lower bound of $D\ge 4/15$, I can prove the upper bound $D\le 1/3$.

For each warrior, imagine placing a token on the $12$ squares that the warrior can attack. Some squares will have multiple tokens. However, you can show that every square will have at most $6$ tokens. Indeed, for any unoccupied square $\mathsf X$, if we partition the $12$ squares that can attack $\mathsf X$ into $6$ attacking pairs as shown in this table, (pairs are labeled $\mathsf A$ through $\mathsf F$), then we see that $\mathsf X$ can be attacked from at most one square in each pair.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & &\mathsf C& &\mathsf D& &  \\\hline
 &\mathsf B& & & &\mathsf C&  \\\hline
\mathsf A& & & & & &\mathsf D \\\hline
 & & &\mathsf X& & &  \\\hline
\mathsf B& & & & & &\mathsf E \\\hline
 &\mathsf A& & & &\mathsf F&  \\\hline
 & &\mathsf F& &\mathsf E& &  \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

This means that each warrior effectively occupies $1+12\times \frac16=3$ squares, so you can have no more than $1/3$ warriors per square.

This is only a "long-run" result, since warriors at the boundary of a grid will place fewer than $12$ tokens. However, this effect is negligible in the long run.

Comment: With your idea, we can show that the inner $ 2014 \times 2014$ grid has at most $1/3 \times 2020^2$ warriors. Adding on at most $2020^2 - 2014^2 $ warriors on the remaining border, that's still less than $ 2/5 \times 2020^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we can find 3 squares that attack each other, then we can place at most 1 warrior on these 3 squares. This is possible, like with:
$ (a, b), (a+1, b+3), (a+3, b+1)$ and $(a+ 5, b), (a+4, b+3), (a+2, b+1)$.

Now, with $ a = 6k+1, k \in [ 1, 336]$ and $b \in [1, 2017]$, we can cover $ 3 \times 2 \times 336 \times 2017$ of the $ 2020^2$ squares. (Verify that these squares are distinct, and lie in our grid.)

These squares contain at most $ 2 \times 336 \times 2017$ warriors.
Addining on the remaining $2020^2 - 3 \times 2 \times 336 \times 2017$ squares, we get at most 1369552 squares for warriors to be on.
This gives us a density of $33.6\% < 40\%$.

---

Notes

- I originally was caught up looking at 5-cycles (because of the ratio $\frac{2}{5}$), till I saw Mike's density bound of $\frac{1}{3}$. This led me to focus on 3-cycles, hence the above solution.
- We just need to make up for the boundary cases (which is minimal in a 2020 grid), of which there are several approaches.
- The upper bound on density is $\frac{1}{3}$, which is easily obtained from the above approach of finding 3 cycles (in an densely packed manner) and accounting for the number of leftover cells (~3 in each row and 1-3 empty columns -> hence density of 0).